# Problems installing Windows 10 after Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I know that the recommended way of dual-booting is Windows first, Ubuntu second but when I purchased my computer, I got fed up with Windows' crap way faster than I expected so I impulsively clean installed Ubuntu on it. Fast-forward a couple of months and I need to install Windows 10 again. I've been trying to do it for 2 days now and I still can't figure out the reason why I can't do it.

I made the bootable flash drive the following way:

- unallocate all memory
- make a GPT
- format it fat32
- mount windows 10 iso to /mnt
- copy /mnt contents to USB location

With Non-Legacy mode, the BIOS doesn't detect the hard drive

With Legacy mode ON, the BIOS detects it but fails to boot from it

When I open the boot options menu with Safe Mode ON, I see only these options:

- ubuntu
- Windows Boot Manager
- My SSD

The Windows Boot Mananer is what remains from the old Windows installation and I suspect is messing everything up but I don't know how. I was thinking of deleting it but then I am not sure if I'll just mess everything up even more. I mounted my EFI partition and ran "$ tree" on it. Here's the result:

```
$ tree
./
└── EFI
    ├── Boot
    │   ├── bootx64.efi
    │   └── bootx64.efi.grb
    ├── Microsoft
    │   └── Boot
    │       ├── bootmgfw.efi
    │       ├── bootmgfw.efi.grb
    │       ├── bootx64.efi
    │       └── bootx64.efi.grb
    └── ubuntu
        ├── fw
        ├── fwupx64.efi
        ├── grub.cfg
        ├── grubx64.efi
        ├── MokManager.efi
        └── shimx64.efi
6 directories, 11 files
```

I'm thinking of just wiping everything off and doing everything "the right way" but I kind of want to just learn what I'm doing wrong and fix it. And I still don't why the BIOS won't detect my flash drive.

These are the partitions of my SSD.

```
$ sudo lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1     259:0    0   477G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0 244.1G  0 part /
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0  15.9G  0 part [SWAP]
└─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0 216.5G  0 part
```

The last one, nvme0n1p4 is a ntfs partition that I made for Windows. I've also tried unpacking the ISO there but I couldn't figure out what exactly to add to the grub.cfg file.

My system is Dell XPS 15(bought January 2016) with 512GB SSD.

the `boot-repair` log is here http://paste2.org/L4jI1fM8

How can I fix this?